# Away3D Broomstick (4), how to fade out model

Tags: flash, air, away3d, stage3d

I have a complex model consisting of different meshes and different materials. What's the easiest way to fade out (slowly make transparent) the whole model over time?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fade out the whole stage?

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same issue. As it seems there is no general way (alpha was removed from ObjectContainer3D) my current solution is to call a fadeOut method for all child objects and have those call their child objects, and have each type of mesh / material implement their own way to fade out. This requires you to extend the classes of all the meshes and materials you use with your own classes though, and requires a different tween for each different mesh/material, but it looks like it's the only way at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

just animate the alpha property for all faces materials to zero value :)